Bags of assorted Lego from Legoland
A few years back I visited the store at Legoland in Billund. They had a huge bin with bags of Lego bricks. No bags seemed to be identical, but most of them had a big overlap in types of pieces. (But some bags stood out, like one bag just with Duplo.)
Lots of the bricks came from sets like 3409 and 3420, and the bricks were unique to those sets, but the bags also had pieces not from those sets. It seemed odd to me with unique pieces from those sets since it was decades since they were released. So it would not seem like it was just some recent production surplus they had to get rid of.
I imagined someone had cleaned up the factory floor and put it into bags, but I know that is of course not how they were made.
Does anyone know how such bags are made?
Are such bags also available at other Legolands?
I bought two of the bags. A few of the pieces in them:

One of these: x45pb02
One of these: x386
Two of these: x45pb03
Two of these: 30488
About 100 of these in red: 3039

Update:
Found an old image which shows part of one of the bags (ignore the markings I've made on the picture). I know it isn't the best one, but it is the only one I have. 

The sets you mention are over 20 years old, was your visit that long ago ?

No, as mentioned in the question my visit was a few years ago. That is also why I found it puzzling with such old pieces

Do you have any pictures of the bags you described? I have one type of bag in mind, but not sure if that was the same one you've seen.

Unfortunately not. However, the bags themselves were just completely clear plastic. No text or other markings.

Did you buy any of these bags? Which parts in particular stood out?

@Tuzi I have updated the question with some details about specific parts.

With the latest update it certainly seems as if LEGO was cleaning the parts storage and bagging all sorts of surplus pieces with minimal organization.

@Alex Found an old picture I have attached now.
